# IComparable type interface for partial ordering

Tags: c#, interface, constraints

I am trying to define a generic function to give the largest value of a set of parameters. It goes like this:

```
    public static TResult Max<TResult>(params TResult[] items)
    {
        TResult result = items[0];
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item > result)
                result = item;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is all well and good, except that the compiler croaks on the "item > result" line. What I need is a way to constrain the TResult to have a > operator (or < would work too.) However, I don't see any readily available interface to do this. Since this is partial ordering it seems a pretty common task. Am I missing something in the gigantic .NET documentation?

Comment: Why is a total ordering (i.e. `IComparable`) not appropriate here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `IComparable`:

```
public static IComparable Max<TResult>(params IComparable[] items)
{
    IComparable result = items[0];
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (item.CompareTo(result) > 0)
            result = item;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: OP doesn’t seem to want to use `IComparable`. It’d be interesting to know why not …

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Right, I just read the title again, although from the text it's not really clear why not.

Comment: `IComparable` is unimplementable if no full ordering exists: `IComparable` requires that all values are comparable. (But the code in the question is not going to work if two values aren't comparable.)

Comment: @Jessica According to the profile picture, rather a chimp than an ass. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no interface that suppport just partial ordering. You can't also use operators in generics.

Most common solution - pass comparator method delegate.

You can also use just part of `IComparable` or `IComparer` intefaces that says "this is grater thant that" and ignore 2 other values.

[`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and 
[`IComparer<in T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) that is used through LINQ queries. I.e. see [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx).